# SAP HANA Reverse Engineering

Tags: genexus, sap

Buen dia,

Estoy tratando de conectar mediante Reverse Engineering a una db SAP HANA y me arroja el siguiente error: java.lang.NullPointerException

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Info KB:
Genexus 17 U5
Java

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1):

yo he probado y me funciona bien, la diferencia que veo es que yo tengo el Cliente HANA instalado y en lugar de usar en DBret, Custom Driver, utilizo Hana JDBC Driver y luego en el campo classpath, coloco \njdbc.jar

Comment: Hola Luis, gracias por tu respuesta. Parece que mi usuario trial no me permite descargar Client HANA, veré como lo resuelvo.